# Objects harder from outside but softer from the inside

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was watching the recent Guardians of the Galaxy movie where Drax jumps into a monster trying to rip it apart from the inside. Star Lord and Gamora feel it is a stupid decision as thickness of its skin is same from out to in as well as vice versa. However there are things like an egg shell that are harder to penetrate out to in but easier vice versa. What is the physical reason for this?

Comment: The outer covering of the egg is harder. It is made up of different material. Your question is too unclear.

Comment: Why are some things easy to penetrate along one direction compared to the opposite direction? We have to go via the same materials after all.

Comment: Egg shells are soft on the inside? Also, what does GotG have anything to do with the actual question?

Comment: Aren't egg shells softer compared to the outside? GotG was mentioned because it  inspired my question. It would be funny if a seemingly mindless move was better than other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materials are structures made out of atoms and molecules. Like structures made out of bricks or girders, they can be strong in one direction and weak in other directions.

Example 1 : a pile of bricks. Stand on them and they will bear a lot of weight. But you can easily knock the pile over sideways or lift the bricks off one by one.

Example 2 : a rubber band resists stretching but easily crumples when you try to compress it.

Like an arch an egg-shell is stronger when compressed, when breaking into it. Then the compressive force is spread out through the arch. The individual stones in a bridge cannot be easily squashed together. The arch is much weaker when the force is applied from beneath. Then it is only the weight of the individual stones in the bridge, and the cement between them, which then holds them together. The strength of gravity and cement is much weaker than the force keeping the stones from being squashed together. When pulling them apart, the cement breaks long before the stones themselves.

Comment: I completely forgot about the spreading of force on arched objects. In theory, if you apply a force normal to the arched surface,would it still be spread evenly?